# (Solved) Programatically change value of Yii2 ActiveForm/Widget Input

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I want to programatically set the value of a form input widget in yii2, but I can't find anyone else trying to do the same. A default value would also work for me. I have the id, so if there is a way to say `$modalForm->contact_id = $my_value;` and make it get the rest of the data from the model, that would be exactly what I'm looking for.

The purpose of this is autofilling the form with data that the user already entered somewhere else.

Here is the beginning of the ActiveForm:

```
<?php $modalForm = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => $addProjectParticipantModelModal->formName(),
        'action' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['url-something-ajax']),
    ]); ?>
```

And here is (one of) the input fields I want to programatically give a value to:

```
echo Form::widget([
    'model'=>$addProjectParticipantModelModal,
    'form'=>$modalForm,
    'columns'=>1,
    'attributes'=>[
        'contact_id'=>[
            'type'=>Form::INPUT_WIDGET,
            'widgetClass' => '\kartik\widgets\Select2',
            'label' => 'Contact Name',
            'options'=>[
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'label' => 'Contact Name',
                    'allowClear' => true,
                    'minimumInputLength' => 2,
                    'ajax' => [
                        'url' => $contactsUrl,
                        'dataType' => 'json',
                        'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }'),
                    ],
                    'placeholder'=>'Pick a contact...',
                    'maxlength' => 60,
                    'id' => 'newParticipantWidget',
                    'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
                    'templateResult' => new JsExpression('function(contact_id) { return contact_id.text; }'),
                    'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function (contact_id) { return contact_id.text; }'),
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

And this is kind of what I'm trying to get to work:

```
if (isset(Yii::$app->session["isReturningAfterContactId"]) && Yii::$app->session["isReturningAfterContactId"] != "") {
    $modalForm->contact_id->$value = Yii::$app->session["isReturningAfterContactId"];
}
```

If I have a look in my Chrome DevTools at the elements on the page, I can see that when I pick something, a new element that looks something like `<option value="an-id-just-like-the-one-i-want-to-insert" data-select="123">Name of contact</option>` pops up, but I don't know how to go about this if it's not even in the DOM before you manually pick something.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Edit: Here is the solution, using Select2 input type & jquery:

```
const defaultOption = new Option(name, id, true, true);
$("#IdOfSelect2Component").append(defaultValue).trigger("change");
```

Comment: daniel did you find the solution?

Comment: @KshitijVerma I first tried adding it to the model, but then the id was just displayed instead of showing the name like I wanted. I ended up making it a select2 input and using jquery like this: `const defaultValue = new Option(name, id, true, true);` `$("#idOfTheSelect").append(defaultValue).trigger("change");`

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: @KshitijVerma yes

Comment: Happy to see your code run :)